# AD B2C Graph API: Search for and Delete Stale accoutns

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We have a use case to delete stale user accounts that haven't perform a certain action within "X" number of days after having been created.

I don't see any claims, attributes, or possible extensions on the users to indicate when an account was created.

How do I programmatically search for accounts that are older than "X" days using the B2C Graph API?

Comment: I can't find it either, the closest thing is the `refreshTokensValidFromDateTime`

Comment: While the name sounds somewhat relevant, if you look at the docs, it's description is quite unrelated, I wouldn't recommend using that. https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/user

Answer (score 0):

**There is not property in the Graph that indicates when a user last signed in.**

Your only option at this point would be to leverage the reporting APIs' [signin Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-sign-in-activity-reference) to build something that periodically polls this API and implements the equivalent of the user.lastSignedIn property you're looking for.